# Mocha dynamic test generation with dynamic data generation

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai, supertest

I have created a method called `testLoginFailed`

```js
let testloginFailed = (app, title, data) => {
  it(title, function (done) {
    request(app)
      .post(apiEndPoints.auth.login)
      .send(data)
      .then((response) => {
        response.statusCode.should.equal(401);
        response.body.error.name.should.equal('Error');
        response.body.error.message.should.equal('login failed');
        response.body.error.code.should.equal('LOGIN_FAILED');
        done();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        done(error);
      });
  });
};
```

and here is my describe block

```
describe('login negative Tests', () => {
before(function () {
    let loginFailedTests = [
        {
            title: 'it should fail user login using mobile because of incorrect mobile',
            data: {
                username: '1223334444',
                password: options.user.password
            }
        }, {
            title: 'it should fail user login using mobile because of incorrect password',
            data: {
                username: options.user.mobileNumber,
                password: options.user.password + '123'
            }
        }
    ];
});

loginFailedTests.forEach((test) => {
    testloginFailed(app, test.title, test.data);
});

});
```

**Problem Statment:**

1. I want to generate dynamic test cases using the function 'testloginFailed' described above.
2. So I am calling the method in a loop with different test data set **testloginFailed**.
3. The array **testloginFailed** is getting initialized in the before block as it needs some data which is in glocal scope using options.

Issue: When I am trying to use this array **testloginFailed** in step 2 above, it says

> ```
>         loginFailedTests.forEach((test) => {
>         ^
> ```
>
> ReferenceError: loginFailedTests is not defined

Comment: Try creating the variable outside the before block and setting it value inside the before block.

Comment: @pulkitsinghal didn't work, as declaring loginFailedTests outside before block gives an empty array to the loop, hence no test is generated

Answer (score 0):

From the doc [RUN CYCLE OVERVIEW](https://mochajs.org/#run-cycle-overview).

> 8. When a test file is loaded, Mocha executes all of its suites and finds–but does not execute–any hooks and tests therein.

> 11. Any “before all” hooks (for the root suite, this only happens once; see root hook plugins)

We know that the `describe()` and its callback will be executed before the `before` hook. The order of execution is `describe()` => `before()` => `it()`

So you should put the initialization process of test data in `describe()` block.

E.g.

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const options = { user: { password: '123', mobileNumber: '321' } };
const app = {};

let testloginFailed = (app, title, data) => {
  it(title, function () {
    expect(1 + 1).to.be.eql(2);
  });
};

describe('login negative Tests', () => {
  let loginFailedTests = [
    {
      title: 'it should fail user login using mobile because of incorrect mobile',
      data: {
        username: '1223334444',
        password: options.user.password,
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'it should fail user login using mobile because of incorrect password',
      data: {
        username: options.user.mobileNumber,
        password: options.user.password + '123',
      },
    },
  ];

  loginFailedTests.forEach((test) => {
    testloginFailed(app, test.title, test.data);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  login negative Tests
    ✓ it should fail user login using mobile because of incorrect mobile
    ✓ it should fail user login using mobile because of incorrect password


  2 passing (5ms)
```